# Newsfeed web part customization

Tags: web-part

[image]

While posting we are getting icon for post image I need to include icon for document sharing, Task and announcements. Is there any way to implement this..?

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me :) Madhu probably wants File, Task and Announcement icons next to the OOTB Picture icon on the Newsfeed web part in order to share not only images but links to other content on his site. And probably wants advice on how to customize that web part or build a custom one.

Comment: The image makes it much clearer that it is the OOTB newsfeed wp we are talking about